# Prevent text from shifting in an input box

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

This ranks low on the list of major problems, but I'm trying to make a ZIP code entry input box that has a border image below it with five long dashes, like so:

[image]

```js
document.getElementById("zip_entry").focus();
```

```css
#zip_entry_container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

input {
  font-family: monospace;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 238px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: left;
}

img {
  width: 238px;
}
```

```html
<div id="zip_entry_container">
  <input id="zip_entry" type="text" maxlength=5 pattern="\d*" />
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kNE4.png" />
</div>
```

Dead simple, right? [Here's a CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/wilson428/pen/prbovO)

I carefully aligned the input and the image just beneath it in CSS so that, using a monospace font, the numbers align exactly with the dashes beneath them UNTIL the fifth digit is entered, at which point, even though I've set `maxlength` to 5, the numbers all shift a few pixels to the left. Here's a [video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2902359/shifting_text.mov) of what I mean, or you can see it yourself in the CodePen link.

I can live with this problem, but I find it really irritating. Any ideas on how I can prevent this default behavior? I've tried messing with `keydown` and preventing the event bubble, but it doesn't stop the browser from moving the text--which moves back to the correct location when you lose focus.

I'd also love it if the cursor was aligned over the center of the dash, but the only way I can think to do this is to make five inputs in a row, and trying this caused all sorts of headaches with a pile of event listeners to switch the focus to the next sibling on `keyup`, switch to the previous sibling on backspace, and otherwise rewrite all the functionality of an input box.

**UPDATE:** I thought I could solve this by immediately calling `.blur()` when the fifth digit is entered, but the shift still happens for a split second. Gah!

Comment: Any tips on how to fix? I've never understood `white-space` that well, but just tried `pre-wrap` and `pre-line` and `nowrap`

Comment: For me, in Chrome, the digits are misaligned - always - even when I enter the second digit. Maybe you'd be better of just going backwards from what the browser gives you after the fifth digit?!

Comment: @Chris Wilson FYI I'm not having this issue on Windows and Google Chrome.

Comment: @MattDiMu That's because Chrome renders the font different. The digits don't match the dashes at all as Nisarg Shah pointed out.

Comment: @ChrisWilson Rewritten my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A major problem (especially in terms of browser compatibility) is, that `font-family: monospace` results in different fonts being applied depending on OS and browser (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family)). In the Codepen provided, Chrome on Windows will use Consolas while Firefox seems to use Courier New. If different fonts are used, letters will have different widths and will therefore result in missaligned letters.

If a text-input gets too large for its content, the text will move to the left (as already mentioned and explained by @Vadim Ovchinnikov). to avoid this, there must be enough space for the cursor. Using 5ch as width unit looks like a good solution to me.

Putting this together:

https://codepen.io/MattDiMu/pen/JyKodN

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the cursor.
If you add some extra pixels to the width (240px instead of 238px) of the input it doesn't shift:

```
input {
  font-family: monospace;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 240px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WExNgL

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of image and JavaScript and use gradients here. Demo:

```css
#zip_entry_container {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

input {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  /* 5 * (1ch + letter-spacing) */ 
  width: 6ch;
  font-size: 80px;
  height: 65px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #000 repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, 
        white 0,
        white 1ch, 
        transparent 0, 
        transparent 1.2ch) 
      0 100%/100% 2px no-repeat;
  /* show background only for content */
  background-clip: content-box;
  /* just add 1px to avoid cursor overflow */
  padding-right: 1px;
  letter-spacing: .2ch;
}
```

```html
<div id="zip_entry_container">
  <input id="zip_entry" type="text" maxlength="5" pattern="\d*" autofocus />
</div>
```

Comment: Only looks good in chrome though...try IE or Firefox and the digits won't match the dashes anymore.

Comment: There was a brief, deleted answer that suggested just lengthening the input to 240px, which worked pretty well. I actually made it 250px and shifted it over 5px to align properly, and looks much better.

Comment: @Danmoreng Totally rewritten answer. Looks good in Chrome, Firefox and Edge (but not IE).

Comment: @ChrisWilson I deleted the answer because it looked bad in Chrome. Seems like it's not possible to make it look good in all browsers.